# How we can access and save object value of foregn model as default value, if the field is empty while saving the related object model?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class ObjectSEO(models.Model):
    object= models.ForeignKey(Objects, related_name='seo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=170, help_text="Please add product meta description, max length 170 characters", default="Some Texts" )
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text="Please add product keywords separated with comma", default="Some Texts" )
    meta_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="object title"  default = Objects.name)
```

Here, I have two models, Objects and ObjectSEO.

In ObjectSEO model > site_name column>  I want to add foreign key Objects name as default value.

How can I do this? Is my approach pythonic?

Comment: what's the issue ?

Comment: default = Objects.name, I am unable to save the required data value just with this model code.

Comment: You should avoid the python keywords, use object_ and Objects_

Comment: If you want to see object name as a default text then you've to use [**`__str__()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#str) to your **Objects** model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method of the ObjectSEO model, to set a default value to the model's field itself.

```
class ObjectSEO(model.Model):
    object= models.ForeignKey(Objects, related_name='seo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=170, help_text="Please add product meta description, max length 170 characters", default="Some Texts" )
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text="Please add product keywords separated with comma", default="Some Texts" )
    meta_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="object title"  default = Objects.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.object.name is not None:
            self.meta_name = self.object.name

        super(ObjectSEO, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is there any way to add just as default? I mean add foreign object name only if no any other input given to the meta_name field.

At present condition, it will add only object name. We cannot change other value.

Comment: Since that is a foreign key, you don't have to save objects name separately. you can access the Object via the foreign key.